# Slowly losing my ability to speak English,and I have no idea how this happened

Tags: american-english

This all started two months ago where all of a sudden reading English and understanding it became harder for me to do. For whatever reason whenever I read something in English now I usually skip over words, grammatic structures or read it perfectly without understanding what I read. This causes me to reread a simple sentence several times. This wasn't something was declining over time, I literally got the disability of struggled reading and struggled understanding English in a single day.

Because of this speaking English has also become a struggle for me since I have to think what I want to say before saying it unlike before where I could just talk spontaneously. Writing is also a problem since I have to think how to properly structure my next sentences more often than usual. I don't know if this is the right subreddit for this but when I googled it I got 0 answers for what I meant and I'm really worried that this could be a problem I only have.

Could this possibly be because of me being a bilingualist and I'm getting better at my second language which is Polish? It isn't like I stopped using English, in fact most of the media I consume is English with only social media being Polish because of friends on it so I have literally no clue why this happened to me. All I want to know is if it isn't brain damage and that if it can be fixed and if it can be fixed then how.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here because this question isn't about the English language.

Comment: This sounds like a medical issue.

Comment: @HotLicks   It does, and a neurologist is the specialist to be seen, to rule out any brain lesion.

Comment: The question should be migrated to a neurology site, if there is one.  Pending that, I'm just going to point out that bilingual people tend to use different areas of the brain to process the two languages.

Comment: @WalterMitty Medical, legal, etc. advice CANNOT be given over the internet for any reason. A trained professional needs to meet the OP in person, with contracts and public liability and all that fun stuff.

Comment: Absolutely agreed.  If anyone reads my comment as advice, then I need to reword it or delete it.

Comment: You seem to have had no trouble in writing your question in perfectly lucid English. Did it take you longer to compose than it would have previously? Which is your first language, English or Polish?

Answer (score 1):

Do Not Close This!!!

Sorry to flame out. I had much the same experience learning German back when and it is related to syntax(!) Just what we discuss here! In German v English the verbs get shoveled to the end of the sentence as they continue to arrive; past, past perfect and even more perfect. It is not unusual to learn how a thing is done, what flavour, color and style only to turn the page to find out what is actually done.

Such changes and differences in sentence structure you are not just learning about in the abstract but incorporating into your thinking. This is most interesting. These are giving you growing pains you have not had since you were a small toddler. The frustration then was fleeting and your illiterate (child) life could go on. Now you are vexed by the lack of clarity as well as the abundance of choices.

As a helper (?!) I would make use of two distinct pens. One would be only for English and the other for Polish. If you can make a habit of holding the English pen it may help cue you for the English you expect to use. The Polish pen will keep you thinking straight while you work on that. I've used similar cues for very different problems.

Do let us know how you make out since we are all about syntax (et al) here.